# Nodes in graph not showing the right label

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Have imported the below matrix using pandas.

```
     name1 name2 name3
name1 0     1     0
name2 1     0     1
name3 0     0     1
```

The graph is showing the nodes as numerics `1, 2, 3`. However, I want the nodes to be `name1, name2, name3`

See the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
datamuse = pd.read_csv('NetworkDatasheet.csv',index_col=0)
print(datamuse)
G = nx.DiGraph(datamuse.values)
nx.draw_random(G, with_labels=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. To get rid of the Dataframe I included the label directly in the Graph attributes.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]], 
                  index=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 
                  columns=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])

# You code works, here it's more explicit
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
# Set labels in each node under the key 'label', create a dict{0: 'name1', ...}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'label', dict(zip(xrange(len(df)), df.index.values)))
# Draw the network and specify the labels
nx.draw_random(G, with_labels=True, labels=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'label'))
```

Comment: thanks for your response. The issue is that the 3x3 matrix was just an example (the real matrix could be many many more rows/columns). I was hoping for a scalble solution, where i don't have to manually define the index/columns

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The dataframe is an example of your real data that you read from a CSV file. This code scales and nothing is defined by hand...